# jQuery AJAX File Upload Freezes

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm making a file upload using jQuery's ajax function. The file upload works perfectly and the data is sent correctly however the HTML doesn't update. When the form is submitted, the buttons aren't re-enabled and the error: 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected Identifier' is displayed in the console. The line number for the error is the first line of my HTML document.

This is my JavaScript code:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('form[data-async]').on('submit', function(e) {
        var $form = $(this);
        var $target = $($form.attr('data-target'));
        $form.find('button').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        $.ajax({
            url: $form.attr('action'),
            type: $form.attr('method'),
            data: new FormData(this),
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success: function(data, status) {
                $target.html(data.response).css('display', 'block');
                $form.find('button').removeAttr('disabled');
            },
            error: function(data, status) {
                $target.html(data.response).css('display', 'block');
                $form.find('button').removeAttr('disabled');
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

The JSON response from the server is also not displayed. This is the response of my PHP code:

```
return Response::json(['response' => 'Image has been uploaded! <script>window.location.href="/image/"' . $filename . '"</script>']);
```

What could be causing the error to be thrown and no response displayed?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Fixed the problem.

```
return Response::json(['response' => 'Image has been uploaded! <script>window.location.href="/image/"' . $filename . '"</script>']);
```

to

```
return Response::json(['response' => 'Image has been uploaded! <script>window.location.href="/image/' . $filename . '"</script>']);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd look at the lines of jquery where you seem to have drifted back into writing PHP code:

```
$target
$form
```

SB $.target or $('#target') or similar, no?